# IF Return Google Apps Script GoogleSheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a simple application that monitors activity (onEdit) on tabs on a spreadsheet except for 2 tabs, call them 'Sheet1' and 'Sheet2'.#

Snippet from code is:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheetName = sheet.getName(); 
  var Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  if (sheetName == Sheet1 || sheetName == Sheet2) return;
```

This does not work and it will monitor changes on these sheets. By trying a different method:

```
  if (sheetName == Sheet1) return;
  if (sheetName == Sheet2) return;
```

Still does not work.

However, when I try just one, like:

```
  if (sheetName == Sheet1) return;
```

Then it will not monitor what is happening on Sheet1.

How can I make it stop looking at both sheets?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Do you think the statement `sheetName == Sheet1` will be true at some point? Because I don't see how it will be. One is (most likely) a string, and the other an object.

Comment: Try ‘if(sheetName==Sheet1.getName())’

Comment: ["Sheet1","Sheet2"].includes(sheet.getName())? return;

Comment: @ScampMichael [``includes()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) has been added to ECMAScript 2015. So unfortunately, this cannot be used at GAS yet. So if you want to use like ``includes()``, how about ``if (~["Sheet1","Sheet2"].indexOf(sheet.getName())) return;``?

Comment: @Tanaika I had a shudder and was coming back to delete when I saw how you pointed out what I was afraid of. Your solution is elegant. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @ScampMichael Welcome. I also hope that es6 can be used at GAS in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run `return`, when `sheetName` is `Sheet1` or `Sheet2` which are the sheet names. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

### Modification points :

- In your script, `sheetName` is string. About `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`, before `var Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")` and `var Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")` are run, those are strings. But after these were run, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` become objects of Sheet. At this time, at `if (sheetName == Sheet1 || sheetName == Sheet2) return;`, "string" and "object" are compared. By this, the comparison what you want cannot be performed. If you want to retrieve "true" from this comparison, you can do it by changing to `sheetName = "Sheet"`. But I don't think this is what you want. So in order to solve this issue, I think that 2 patterns for your situation. Please check them and select the pattern you want.

### Pattern 1

`sheetName` is compared by `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` which are the sheet names.

#### Modified script :

```
var sheetName = sheet.getName();
if (sheetName == "Sheet1" || sheetName == "Sheet2") return;
```

### Pattern 2

Although I'm not sure about `sheet` of `sheet.getName()` from your question, if you want to compare the sheets after it confirms whether `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` are existing in the active spreadsheet, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script :

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetName = sheet.getName(); 
var Sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var Sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
if ((Sheet1 && sheetName == Sheet1.getName()) || (Sheet2 && Sheet2.getName())) return;
```

#### Note :

- In this modified script, `Sheet1 &&` of `Sheet1 && sheetName == Sheet1.getName()` is used for checking the existence of `Sheet1`. `Sheet2` is the same as well.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.